# Silverlight Video - playing Virtual Video Clips

Tags: silverlight, video

I have a requirement to play only a portion of a larger video file in Silverlight and I am wondering if this is possible in a dynamic way. We want to avoid having to cut up a larger video into smaller clips that will appear at different locations on the site.

thanks
Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory you could yes, you could have the MediaElement start a specific position and then monitor the playback and stop the media when it hits another position.  You could do this probably easier (than monitoring time) by providing markers in the media and just listen for the marker events, then start/stop as needed.